# runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6030000000d0 overflowed to 0x6030000000cc (stl_vector.h)

Tags: c++, runtime-error, binary-search

Problem Name: Peak Index in Mountain Array

The problem requires finding the index of the peak element in a mountain array. The peak element is defined as an element that is greater than its neighbors. The array is guaranteed to have a mountain pattern.

Such that:
`arr[0] < arr[1] < ... < arr[i - 1] < arr[i]`  & `arr[i] > arr[i + 1] > ... > arr[arr.length - 1]` where `i` is the needed index.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
class Solution {
public:
    int peakIndexInMountainArray(vector<int>& arr) {
        int left = 0, right = arr.size() - 1;
        int mid;
        while (left <= right) {
            mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
            if (arr[mid] > arr[mid - 1] && arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]) {
                return mid;
            } else if (arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1]) {
                left = mid + 1;
            } else {
                right = mid - 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }  
};
```

I tried some test cases on it, few are working fine, but when I use the input `{3, 5, 3, 2, 0}`, the code triggers the runtime error.
`runtime error: addition of unsigned offset to 0x6030000000d0 overflowed to 0x6030000000cc (stl_vector.h)`

I am able to run it on my own compiler, but getting this error on Leetcode after submiting the code.

Comment: The code seem to be some kind of binary search. If you have studied standard algorithms you should have known that binary search *requires* the input to be ordered (sorted).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, the input is needed to be sorted. But the input does have a pattern `arr[0] < arr[1] < ... < arr[i - 1] < arr[i] ` & `arr[i] > arr[i + 1] > ... > arr[arr.length - 1]` where `i` is the needed index. I searched a bit about this and Binary Search is used to solve this problem. It's just that my implementation might need some debugging.

Comment: `arr[mid + 1]` is going to peek at `arr[arr.size()]` which is out of bounds

Comment: Create a proper [mre], with the input hard-coded into the `main` function. Then you can easily debug it locally om your own system. Use tools such as compiler sanitizers or memory debuggers like Valgrind. Or simply change all vector access using `[]` to use the `at` function, which will throw an exception when you go out of bounds.

Comment: Have you tried to compile your code locally and test it with a debugger attached? Being able to debug your own code is a required skill and not something leetcode will teach you (in fact leetcode will probably teach you a lot of bad C++ habits instead)

Comment: Much better sources to learn c++ from are : A [recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or have a go at https://www.learncpp.com/ (that's pretty decent, and pretty up-to-date).
 For C++ reference material use : [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/). And after you learned the C++ basics from those sources, look at the [C++ coreguidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) regularely to keep up-to-date with the latest guidelines.

Comment: Another cargo cult adept. Congrats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never check if `mid` is `0` before accessing `arr[mid-1]` and you never check if `mid` is `arr.size() - 1` before accessing `arr[mid+1]`. Both these failures will lead to accesses out of bounds.

Adding checks before accesses should make it work according to the intended design.

```cpp
int peakIndexInMountainArray(const std::vector<int>& arr) {
    int left = 0, right = arr.size();
    int mid;
    while (left < right) {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;

        bool low = (mid == 0) || (arr[mid] > arr[mid - 1]);
//                 ^^^^^^^^^^
        bool high = (mid == (arr.size() - 1)) || (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]);
//                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        if (low && high) {
            return mid;
        } else if (low) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else {
            right = mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```